# JavaScript accessor properties in constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, constructor

I've seen accessor properties defined via the `get` and `set` keywords in object literals and property descriptors.

(From [Speaking JavaScript](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch17.html#getters_setters)):

```
// Object literal
var obj = {
    get foo() {
        return 'getter';
    },
    set foo(value) {
        console.log('setter: '+value);
    }
};

// Property descriptor
var obj = Object.create(
    Object.prototype, {  // object with property descriptors
        foo: {  // property descriptor
            get: function () {
                return 'getter';
            },
            set: function (value) {
                console.log('setter: '+value);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

(From [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)):

```
// Adding to an object's prototype
Object.defineProperty(TextCell.prototype, "heightProp", {
  get: function() { return this.text.length; }
});
```

But say you're using a *constructor* to create objects. I haven't seen examples of an accessor being defined within a constructor itself (i.e. so that the accessor is an own property of an object.)

Using `Object.defineProperty` in the constuctor seems to work:

```
function V(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // accessor (getter) `length`
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
      get: function () { return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y); } // (1)
    });
}
```

Is there any difference in the accessor property defined as in (1) in the constructor above, and accessor properties defined as in the earlier patterns (object literals, property descriptors directly on the object)?

(And are there objective reasons not to define getters and setters in constructors outside of coding style preference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference in the accessor property defined as in (1) in the constructor above, and accessor properties defined as in the earlier patterns (object literals, property descriptors directly on the object)?

There's no difference between (1) and your previous use of `defineProperty`, no. There is a difference between it and your object initializer at the top (`var obj = ...`): The `foo` property is *enumerable*, whereas the `length` property in your (1) example and the `heightProp` in your example from Eloquent JavaScript are not (because the default for `defineProperty` is to define it non-enumerable; you can change that by adding `enumerable: true`).

> (And are there objective reasons not to define getters and setters in constructors outside of coding style preference?)

No. I will note that your particular example doesn't benefit from being an own property, though; so I'd probably define it on `V.prototype`. But other than the usual benefits of using things defined on prototypes (sharing, reusability, dynamicism), there's no particular reason to prefer that. Defining it once means fewer function objects, but objects are fairly cheap.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference in the accessor property defined as in (1) in the constructor above, and accessor properties defined as in the earlier patterns (object literals, property descriptors directly on the object)?

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) allows for finer-grained control over how the getter/setter is defined.

> (And are there objective reasons not to define getters and setters in constructors outside of coding style preference?)

Yes, depending on your purpose.

#### Advantages of `prototype`:

1. Methods added to the prototype are shared by every instance. Cheap though a new instance may be, it will always less-memory and fewer opcodes to add it to the prototype.
2. Many code hinters will include prototype properties and methods, but not those only set in constructors.
3. Having the property in the prototype could signal that it has not been overwritten by an instance.
4. It's the modern ECMAScript way.

```
([]).hasOwnProperty('length') // true, old pre-getter array.
(new Uint8Array(1)).hasOwnProperty('length') // false, new typed array.
```

#### Advantages of per-instance:

You can access private properties of the constructors closure, which can be desirable for some things (`WeakMap` could make this completely unnecessary though).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new instance object with the function constructor pattern ,in your code for each instance created you will have a getter that is a function (namely an other object) therefore you are creating two objects for every instance. Instead in the other solution where you attach the getter method to the prototype you will have only a getter for all the object created. Furthemore in the object literal notation the attributes `configurable` and `enumerable` will be `true` by default instead with the function `defineProperty` they will be `false` by default but you can solve this difference explicitly setting these attributes in the `V` function or you can do in this way:

```
function V(x, y) {
    return { x,
             y,
             get length(){
                return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
             }
           };
    }
```

You can return the object with the object literal notation inside the constructor. Note the ES6 property value shortand.  In this way configurable and enumerable will be `true` for the `length property`